# check if checkbox has been selected

Tags: jquery

I'm developing a website that dynamically adds some formfields (including checkboxes) and related (jquery) validation rules . UPDATE (clarification): For some validation I need to add a validation methods dynamiccally (after the related formfields have been created). The problem relates to the validation code for determining whether the field is required or not. The field should be required if the checkbox has been set. The added validation rules work with respect to validating on 'minlength', 'maxlength' and 'integer', but not on 'required'. I think I understand why my code for validating on 'required' does not work (because of listitem) but I dont know how to correct this code...

(I looked at the related topics on this site as well as on http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)

javascript code element for adding checkbox formfield (with increasing listitemnr...):

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check'+ listitem +'" name="productselection'+ listitem +'" value="' + this.productid[listitem] + '">
```

UPDATE: code adding validation method which includes code for checking checkbox is checked:

```
if ($("#nrofparts"+listitem).length > 0) { //elements exists?
                    //console.log("added VAL: "+listitem);
                    $("#nrofparts"+listitem).rules("add", { 
                        required: function(element) {return ($('#check'+listitem).is(':checked') );},
                        minlength: 1,
                        maxlength: 3,
                        integer:true, 

                    }
                ); //$("#investmentfix"+currindex).rules add
```

Comment: What do you want with this `id="check'+ listitem +'"` and `name="productselection'+ listitem +'"` in your HTML?

Comment: they are just id's and names with increasing (listitem)numbers. The The checkbox is meant for the user to select (or not select) a related product. Some more javascript code is using the id for some calculations... I just also tried the validation code "$('#check'+listitem).is(':checked')" but that doesnt seem to work either...

Answer (score 0):

Just try with:

```
if ( $('#check' + listitem).is(':checked') ) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the [`:checked`](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) usage. It matches all input elements that are checked (apart from `select`)

```
if ($('#check' + listitem).is(':checked')) {
    // your code here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the delegation .on so  I guess you are getting it as zero.As u said you are going to load the some contents dynamically, whenever you load the contents on the page dynamically you need to use .on() for eg: $('').on('click',function_name); The below code will help you.

```
      var countChecked = function() {
        var n = $( "input:checked" ).length;
         $( "div" ).text( n + " checked!" );
      };

      $( "input[type=checkbox]" ).on( "click", countChecked );
```

Here is the fiddle **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SgBrY/)**

Comment: hnx for all your comments. I tried the suggestions and then concluded I should have explained the wider context. Pls see the updated text above. – user2543182